# Replace one image with another using onTouch in android

Tags: android

I am a beginner working with graphics. Right now I have an image displayed in random places on the screen. What I would like to do that if the image is touched, it should be replaced by another image. How can I do that?
Another thing I currently am using a class within a class.Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener{

MyGameGraphics myGraphics;
TextView tvScore, tvPlayerScore;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tvScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showScore);
    tvPlayerScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playerScore);

    myGraphics = new GraphicsMain(this);

    myGraphics.setOnTouchListener(this);

    setContentView(myGraphics);




    }

@Override
protected void onPause(){

    super.onPause();
    myGraphics.pause();


}

@Override
protected void onResume(){

    super.onResume();
    myGraphics.resume();
}






@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // How to change image using touch event here?

    return false;

}





public class MyGameGraphics extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    Boolean isRunning = false;
    int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};





    public MyGameGraphics(Context context) {

        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();

    }

      public void pause(){

          isRunning = false;
          while(true){

              try {


                ourThread.join();


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();


            }

             break; 
          }
          ourThread = null;

      }

      public void resume(){

          isRunning = true;
          ourThread = new Thread(this);
          ourThread.start();

      }


    @Override
    public void run() {



        while(isRunning){

            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
             continue;

            Canvas ourCanvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            ourCanvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);


            Random rn = new Random();
            int location = rn.nextInt(12);

            for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){

                try {

            Random rn2 = new Random();
            int generateWidthLocation = rn2.nextInt(420);
            int generateHeightLocation = rn2.nextInt(600);


            Bitmap btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), images[location]);
            ourCanvas.drawBitmap(btmp, generateWidthLocation, generateHeightLocation,  null);

                ourThread.sleep(3000);




            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }






            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(ourCanvas);

        }



             }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the OnTouch method, the `event` parameter has two functions : `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`.

Then  you just need to keep the generateWidthLocation and generateHeightLocation for the current position and you can easily determine if the image is touched or not (you also need to keep the height/width of the image).

You might need to check if the OnTouch method is called when the user touches the screens, moves his finger or stops to touch it : `event.getAction()` which is either `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` or `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

EDIT : In your MyGameGraphics add the following properties :

```
    int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2 };
    int currentXImageLocation = 0;
    int currentYImageLocation = 0;
    int currentImageWidth = 0;
    int currentImageHeight = 0;
```

And after `ourCanvas.drawBitmap(btmp, generateWidthLocation, generateHeightLocation, null);` add :

```
    currentXImageLocation = generateWidthLocation;
    currentYImageLocation = generateHeightLocation;
    currentImageHeight = btmp.getHeight();
    currentImageWidth = btmp.getWidth();
```

Then add this function in your MyGameGraphics class :

```
    public boolean isImageTouched(float x, float y)
    {
        boolean result = false;

        if(x > currentXImageLocation && x < currentXImageLocation + currentImageWidth 
                && y > currentYImageLocation && y < currentYImageLocation + currentImageHeight)
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And finally in the OnTouch method :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        if(myGraphics.isImageTouched(event.getX(), event.getY()))
        {
            //Image was touched, do something...
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: could you please explain it with code, I wasn't able to implement it.Thanks